# Struggling with platinum wire/hotwire

Tags: heat

I am trying to heat a thin platinum wire with a controllable power supply, using what I believe to be Joule heating. It doesn't have to get intensely hot, the main application is observing behavior of materials when heated by this wire over a modest range of temperature. I am having some problems with building it.

How exactly should my platinum wire be connected to the power supply? Is it simply one end of the wire on the positive, the other end on the negative? Wouldn't this short the circuit? Is there a resistor required somewhere, or is platinum resistive enough?

Comment: You don't need a resistor if your power supply has good voltage resolution at low levels or good current limiting at low levels. But if it doesn't, or if you don't know what you're doing add a resistor.

Comment: First, measure the resistance of that wire, and learn (e.g. from books) how that resistance varies with temperature for platinum. If the resistance is high enough, it isn't considered a short circuit.

Comment: @user_1818839 once I calculate this total resistance of the wire, how do I know if it is "high enough" to avoid a short circuit?

Comment: If the PSU can supply enough current at its rated voltage (use Ohm's Law), then you can consider it a resistive load, not a short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

"Wouldn't this short the circuit? "

Oh, yes. In the process it will cause the power supply to provide a high current at low voltage.

What you need to do is to use a power supply with a good current-limit protection. Set the output voltage to something like 1 volt, and the current limit to a convenient value. I don't know what that value would be, since I don't know how long your wire is, what its diameter is, or how much power you want to dissipate.

You'll have to figure that out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Other than superconductors, all wires will have some resistance. It would be helpful to know what the resistance of yours is.

You will need a low voltage, high current, power supply to power it. Something that can deliver several amps without overheating.